# get the value of an object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, writeablebitmapex

First, I'm just a starter and now writing a visual force page and apex

Basically, I have objects A and B, A is master and B is detail, every time creating a B I will set the default balance value as the same as A, my code is as below:

```
 //visual force page:
 <apex:inputField value="{!acc.A__c}"/>

 //apex code:
 public void upgrade(){
        A__c bc;
        bc.Id  = acc.A__c;
        Decimal str = bc.Balance__c;
        acc.Balance__c = str;
        insert acc;
}
```

it didn't work for some reasons, so is there any way to get the value of the master A_*c and copy it into the same field B*_c??

any helps are welcomed!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Visualforce to achieve that, a [workflow rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm) or maybe [form prepopulation trick](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) is sufficient.

Make a new rule on the detail object with criteria "every time record is created" and the action would be a field update that sets details `Balance` field. The formula to which it should be set is simply `Master__r.Balance__c`, `A__r.Balance__c` or hovewer you have named the master-detail field.

If you insist on using visualforce - your code is completely messed up (starting from the fact that in normal circumstances you never assign anything to `Id` field).

If the idea is that your user will fill in the lookup from B to A (the `A__c` field), then:

```
B__c b = new B__c();
// Some time later user fills in the lookup
// b.A__c = 'some id here';
// and hits save button.

public void save(){
    if(b.A__c != null){
        A__c selectedA = [SELECT Id, Name, Balance__c FROM A__c WHERE Id = :b.A__c];
        b.Balance__c = selectedA.Balance__c;
    }
    insert b;
}
```